# Basic way to handle login with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a client-side app using create-react-app. The application renders a login component with a basic form and I want to load another component (which will be the main application) on successful login.

**The validation and the login logic is not the issue at the moment** because first I'm trying to figure out a simple way to dismount the login component and load another component on the submit event.

```
class Login extends Component {

    handleLogin(){
        // trigger to load Main.js
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // form elements here

            <div className="submit">
                <input className="button-signin" value="Sign In" type="submit"
                    onClick={this.handleLogin}/>
                </div>
            );
    }
}
```

What would be the easiest way to switch to another component (which I called Main.js in this example) on submit event?

Comment: Do you want to route or redirect?  Because when you say redirect it sounds like you want to change window.location

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I didn't mean to use redirect in that way, I've rephrased the question to "load another component" instead of redirect. If I can just dismount the login component and mount the main application component, I'd be happy. But if routing is the way to go, then yes that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [React router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)? It makes really easy to define routes and assign a Component to each of them. Then you can also establish conditions for accessing each route. [There is an example in the official docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js) that seems to match your requirements.

```
<Router history={withExampleBasename(browserHistory, __dirname)}>
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
  <Route path="about" component={About} />
  <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
</Route>
```

The method `requireAuth` will be checked each time you try to access the route `dashboard` (which will show the component `Dashboard`). If you are using token-based authentication, you might have a token stored in the localStorage and check if it's present in `requireAuth`.

Your method `handleLogin` would call the backend, log the user in (store the token in localStorage if that's how the login is handled) and then redirect to the dashboard route.

Comment: I know it's outside of the scope but I see some examples with BrowserHistory and some with HashHistory. Both of them seem to work, would you favor one over the other in a client-side project?

Comment: You can find the differences [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory). There are some differences between them. Basically HashHistory is easier to start with but you should use BrowserHistory in production because the URLs are cleaner.